# Bad Request (400) when trying to create buy order on Steam

Tags: javascript, python, http, cookies, request

I'm making a Python bot that interacts with the Steam market(http://steamcommunity.com/market). All is going well, however I am stuck on creating a buy order. I have based my Python(3) code on the following javascript:

```
$J.ajax( {
    url: 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/createbuyorder/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        sessionid: g_sessionID,
        currency: g_rgWalletInfo['wallet_currency'],
        appid: this.m_unAppId, // ITEM?
        market_hash_name: this.m_strMarketHashName,
        price_total: price_total,
        quantity: quantity
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }
} ).done( function ( data ) {
    CreateBuyOrderDialog.OnCreateBuyOrderComplete( { responseJSON: data } );
} ).fail( function( jqxhr ) {
    // jquery doesn't parse json on fail
    var data = $J.parseJSON( jqxhr.responseText );
    CreateBuyOrderDialog.OnCreateBuyOrderComplete( { responseJSON: data } );
} );
```

where the currency/appid/price_total/quantity are integers and sessionid and market_hash_name a string. I have reconstructed this code into Python 3:

```
cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

#before the request is made, cookies are 'created' by doing other requests on the same website

def placeOrder():

    url = 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/createbuyorder'
    values = {'sessionid' : self.sessionid,
              'currency' : '3',
              'appid' : '730',
              'market_hash_name' : 'Chroma 2 Case',
              'price_total' : '4',
              'quantity' : '1'}
    headers = {'Accept' : '*/*',
               'Content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
               'Referer' : 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Chroma%202%20Case',
               'Accept-Language' : 'nl-NL',
               'Origin' : 'http://steamcommunity.com',
               'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate',
               'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko',
               'Host' : 'steamcommunity.com',
               'Connection' : 'Keep-Alive',
               'Cache-Control' : 'no-cache'}
    post = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
    binary_data = post.encode('utf-8')
    request = urllib.request.Request(url, binary_data, headers)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)

    data = json.loads(response.decode('utf-8'))
```

However when calling the `placeOrder()` function this error is returned: `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request`.

Why does this create a bad request? Because I have exactly reproduced the headers and cookies by creating a 'real' request on this url http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Chroma%202%20Case# by buying an item.

Why could the website return a bad request? What is most likely? (eg. missing cookie, missing header, missed step, etc.)

Help is appreciated!

Comment: I have also run into same problem. I have exactly reproduced the headers and cookies by creating a real request on the browser. How did you solve the error

Answer (score 0):

The `url`, `http://steamcommunity.com/market/createbuyorder` is missing a trailing `/` in your Python code, that's one difference.

Hard to debug this, is the data being sent the same?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe its to late but i got some suggestions.
The url in the Ajax request is "https" not "http" might be important here, another possible reason for the Bad Request could be the Credentials, try to use the headers: 
`"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://steamcommunity.com"`and `"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"`. Please tell me if you solved the Problem and how.

Comment: Yeh I definitely solved it, I don't know how anymore though. If you are by any chance also making a bot, let me know :> - I got mine to fully work

Comment: Yeah im trying myself on a bot also. I solved the problem with the bad request yesterday and starting now to make it work fine.

Comment: I got one fully working with persistent session and all that. I bought a VPS because I had bad connection with host from home however for some reason the script returns bad requests (which mostly means that somebody already bought it with listingsbuying) however it just doesn't work from my VPS... If you want I can just send you my script (if you want, cause it's nicer to code it yourself) and it's only a script for items with listingids, so not the buyorder ones. Before I made my real steambot I made this maybe its of use to you: https://github.com/wagenaartje/steamBot/blob/master/steamBot.py

Comment: My real steambot is really a script and is much faster... I have made profit with it but not super-duper much (maybe max 50 cents per day if you run it on a machine with good ping)... From my bad ping, max 20 cents per day if you run it all day long. Let me know if you want me to send the code...

Comment: Im interested in the part how you managed to scan the markt for low priced items. It takes much longer if you send a request when you are logged in. Yeah it would be nice to see your code.

Comment: Ill send it soon. About the longtime login thingy, I remember in my earlier version I used `http.client` to check for items and `urllib.request` just for logged-in session requests. In my newer version however I abandonded http.client, as I did not see a very big difference (a matter of 0.1 milliseconds maybe) and as my ping was >30 it was relatively low.

Comment: here is the link to the download https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1Vrr2RaX38nSXNvWDdMUkhyWUE/view?usp=sharing I will remove it soon. I don't think you'll use it directly, but feel free to use the code as i'm working in C# as it is much faster than Python.